# how to generate subsets from a query in postgres?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I need subsets of tuples for a given query. For example ,  if I need to find list of all employees who are older than 25 and limit that to atmost 5. how do I generate various subsets for the same ?

```
# select * from employee where age > 25 ;  
will list all the employee whose age is > 25 

tupleid = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 }

#select * from employee where age > 25 limit 5 ;
will list any 5 tuples from it.

tupleid on first time execution = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

But I need some kind of permutation of the 5 set tuple where I get
{1,2,3,4,5} {2,3,4,5,6} .. and so on ..

Is there a way to generate the same in sql / postgres  ?

Edit 1:
Since the question dint seem to be clear at first.

I have added a  sample table and sql Query I was talking about . [sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69a0c/2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69a0c/2) If you see the output of the 2nd query I only get to see [1,2,3,4,5] tuples are the answer. I want [1,2,3,4,5] , [1,2,3,4,6] , [1,2,3,4,7] and soo on unique combinations as the answer .

Comment: Postgres, or MySQL?  This question is tagged both.

Comment: I am looking for a generic approach which may work in both RDBMS

Comment: Define `some kind of permutation`. `{1,2,3,4,5}`,  `{2,3,4,5,6}` are not permutations ...

Answer (score 1):

To get your "kind of permutations", use `OFFSET`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   employee
WHERE  age > 25
ORDER  BY employee_id    -- or whatever
OFFSET 1
LIMIT  5;
```

To get a *random* sample:

```
SELECT *
FROM   employee
WHERE  age > 25
ORDER  BY random()
LIMIT  5;
```

Postgres. In MySQL you can use `RAND()` instead.

Comment: permutation may not be good choice of word in here. I meant i need combinations of various possible solutions.  Rand() will not guarantee unique pairs and offset <var> just skips the <first> tuple  and so on..  for a given query the answer I am expecting to fetch is 
9!  combinations in the above example. Since the result contains 9 tuples. Let me know, If I have confused you more.

Comment: @Rahul: You did it. Confused me more. I suppose you add example values and example result to your question. Or use an SQLfiddle for that and add the link in your question. Random example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6d21d/1

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This is the sample table and sql Query I was talking about .  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69a0c/2   If you see the  output of the 2nd query I only get to see  [1,2,3,4,5] tuples are the answer. I want [1,2,3,4,5]  ,  [1,2,3,4,6] , [1,2,3,4,7] and soo on unique combinations as the answer .